# MVC Routing question

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute("Archive", "archive/{year}", new
    {
        controller = "Archive",
        action = "Results"
    }
);
```

I have the route working correctly, but I would like my url to show as follows:

```
http://mysite.com/archive/2008
```

when I click on the search button instead of just:

```
http://mysite.com/archive
```

I DON'T want to do this by creating an action link to that url, I want the submit button to do it.

EDIT:

More info. On my home page, I have a textbox that, when the submit button is clicked, passes the year value typed in the textbox to the Action method Results in my Archive controller that takes one parameter, year.  I am getting the correct value in the method right now, I just want the year displayed in the url as well.  If I manually type in the year in the url like above, it works just as I expect as well.

THANKS!

Comment: How do you construct your Url? Do you construct it with the Html.Form helper? Could you provide a snippet of the area where you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the Year parameter to the BeginForm(), like:

```
<% 
    using (Html.BeginForm("Results", "Archive", new { year = DateTime.Now.Year }))
    {
        // form
    }
%>
```

Comment: I need this value to come from the previous forms post action, not from the current year.

Comment: DateTime.Now.Year was only used an example you can set it to whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the default value for the **`{year}`** parameter as **`2008`** in that case. Thus, the route you need is as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute("Archive", 
  "archive/{year}", 
  new { controller = "Archive", action = "Results", year = 2008 } );
```

You can also make this dynamic:

```
routes.MapRoute("Archive", 
  "archive/{year}", 
  new { controller = "Archive", action = "Results", year = DateTime.Now.Year } );
```

However, I should note that this is dynamic only at Web Application start time, since the routes are defined at `Application_Start`, which happens once, and the value of `DateTime.Now.Year` is cached as the value at that time.

Comment: providing a default value just ensures a value gets passed to my handling action, it doesn't put anything in as far as my url structure is concerned

Comment: I am sorry, you are right. The answer I provide just makes sure that you get a correct default value. I recommend you follow veggerby's response which seems to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could also have a hidden form element named "year" that gets posted when you submit the form

```
<%=Html.Hidden("year",2008) %>
```

Comment: I need the content to be dynamic from the previous page, not hard coded to 2008.